# Converting datetime to short date from a declared table in sql

Tags: sql, datetime

This is my first question on StackOverflow so I apologize for this most likely being formatted incorrectly. I am very new to sql language and am having trouble with the following query:

I have a declared table with one row selecting for a datetime (OccurrenceGroupID) and would like to have that date show up with short date formatting in the query results.

```
--Select for Occurrence Group
Declare @A3 table (OccurrenceGroupID datetime)
insert into @A3
select OccurrenceGroup as OccurrenceGroup, 
Convert(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 101) as [MM/DD/YYYY]
from tblOccurrenceGroup
where occurrencegroupid = @occurrencegroupid
```

I get the error message "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you are selecting two columns and trying to insert the result set into a table with only one column.

Regardless of this you are converting a `datetime` to a `varchar` presumably for presentation reasons and then wanting to insert it into a column of type `datetime` which doesn't make much sense. Always leave the formatting of dates to the client application.

Comment: Very good point vote up these are both correct I only noticed the one

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had trouble when reformatting the date when pulling the result into an access textbox and tried to do it this way as a workaround. Anyways just got it working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have declared it as datetime

```
Declare @A3 table (OccurrenceGroupID datetime)
```

so it expects a date and a time you the go on to say

```
 Convert(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(), 101) as [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

you then say convert the varchar as MM/DD/YYYY therefor it is contradictory to your first statement